# Are there vegan formula options for infants?

Tags: veganism, dairy-substitutes, children

If I am unable to breastfeed and I want to avoid dairy-based products, what are my options for formula?

Answer (score 13):

There are soy formulas that are suitable for infants from birth.
For example, [SMA Wysoy Soya Infant formula](https://www.smababy.co.uk/formula-milk/wysoy-infant-formula/)

However, soy formulas are reinforced with vitamins and minerals and some of these (vitamin D) contain animal derivatives (lanolin, sheep's wool) which make them not vegan.

There are breastmilk banks where lactating women donate their breast milk for mothers who are struggling to produce their own. It would be worth searching for that in your area.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a vegan infant formula made by French company Prémibio. The product is rice-based and is called [Prémiriz](https://www.premibio.fr/premiriz/). There are three stages available:

- stage 1 - 0-6 months
- stage 2 - 6-12 months
- stage 3 - 12-36 months

Prémiriz is available from [this US based website](https://groworganicbaby.com/72-premiriz) and [this French one](https://www.biodidoo.com/premiriz-baby-milk-0-6-months-900g-premibio-a1378-en.html), for example. Some information about it from the latter is excerpted below:

> Prémiriz covers all your baby's needs, including proteins and essential amino acids. Similarly, Prémiriz ensures an intake of calcium and vitamin D3 exclusively from plant origin sources. Prémiriz is a certified vegan formula and thus does not contain any animal product or by-product.
>
> Prémiriz is suitable for vegan babies.
>
> Prémiriz supply of nutrients is identical to regular infant milk based on cow's or goat's milk protein.

The first site mentioned above apparently [ships pretty much anywhere](https://groworganicbaby.com/content/1-shipping). Other online shops seem to carry it too so I guess it's gained in popularity and become easier to get hold of since I originally wrote this answer, which is great news.